# Removing b' in python django

Tags: python, django

I have a string showing as b'value' i want to remove the b' part.
AFTER Searching thru stackoverflow, i tried below but didnt work

> 

```
{% for item in row %}
35                                                  <td>{{ item.decode('UTF-8') }}</td>
36                                              {% endfor %}
```

I get error Could not parse the remainder: '('UTF-8')' from 'item.decode('UTF-8')'

Comment: Please post the error stack trace, along with the context for `item`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
>>> b'value'.decode('UTF-8')
```

Comment: can you show me how in that html? cause {{ item }} returns the value as b'value'

Comment: Why you not convert the value în views.py? and then pass it to the template?

Comment: so what should I do {{ item }} .decode('UTF-8') How do i call it in html?

Comment: because i am not responsible on that part of the code, i am getting it from the other developer.

Comment: You need a language to make that conversion. You can try with JavaScript but I don t know if will work

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove the `b'` part because it is a byte string. The `b'` isn't part of the string. You have to decode it using `.decode` method available to strings.

```
>>> x = b'hello'
>>> x
b'hello'
>>>x.decode("utf8")
'hello'
```